# Finding a and b

Tags: polynomials

The remainder when a polynomial $f(x)$ is divided by $(x-2)(x+3)$ is $ax+b$. When $f(x)$ is divided by $(x-2)$, then remainder is $5$. $(x+3)$ is a factor of $f(x)$. Find the values of $a$ and $b$. I am thinking of using the remainder and factor theorem to solve this however their quotients are different. Can anyone please show me how? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumptions are that there are polynomials $q,s,t$ such that
$$
\begin{cases}
f(x) = (x-2)(x+3) q(x) &+ a x + b\\
f(x) = (x -2) s(x) &+ 5\\
f(x) = (x + 3) t(x)
\end{cases}
$$

Now calculate $f(2)$ and $f(-3)$.

Comment: I can only find out that f(2)=5 and f(-3)=0 by this. How can I find a and b?

Comment: Plug first $x = 2$ and then $x = -3$ in the first equation to get other expressions for $f(2)$ and $f(-3)$. Equate to the expressions you already have.

Comment: But then I still have q(x) unknown

Comment: Nobody asked you to determine $q(x)$, which is an impossible task. You are only looking for $a$ and $b$. Why don't you substitute $x = 2$ in the first equation and see what you get, ***please***?

Comment: I finally understand this now thank you so much!

Comment: @Estudiantekriss, you're welcome. If you like my answer, please consider upvoting/accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

Simple: first write  $\;f(x)=(x+3)g(x)$, and perform the *Euclidean division* of $g(x)$ by $x-2$:
$$g(x)=(x-2)q(x)+g(2).$$
Now $f(2)=5g(2)$, so that
$$f(x)=(x-2)(x+3)q(x)+ g(2)(x+3)=(x-2)(x+3)q(x)+ \underbrace{\frac{f(2)}5(x+3)}_{\text{remainder}}. $$

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are on the right track.

Let *f*(*x*) = (*x*-2)(*x*+3) x *m* + (*ax* + *b*).

We know *f*(2) = 5, so (2-2)(2+3) x *m* + (2 *a* + *b*) = 5
And similarly *f*(-3) = 0, so (-3-2)(-3+3) x *m* + (-3 *a* + *b*) = 0

This gives 2 equations

(2 *a* + *b*) = 5, and

(-3 *a* + *b*) = 0

Which you can solve to give *a*=1 and *b*=3

Answer (score 0):

#### Hint:

If $$f(x)=(x-\alpha)g(x)+r$$
then $r=f(\alpha)$

Really, $x=\alpha$ $f(\alpha)=0+r$

Then $$f(x)=(x-2)(x+3)+ax+b$$

$f(2)=5$ and $f(-3)=0$

$$2a+b=5$$
$$-3a+b=0$$

$$a=1, b=3$$